# How do I fix a "could not be parsed" Visual Studio Code configuration error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I am currently setting up Visual Studio Code for C++ usage, however when setting up my compiler path in `edit configuration (UI)` to `C:\MinGW65\mingw64\bin\g++.exe` it shows up with the error :

> [27/04/2021, 10:25:03 pm] "C:\MinGW64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'Start' will be used instead.

Note: `Start` is the name of current opened directory.

I have tried setting up my compiler path to: `C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe`, which shows up with no errors however `gcc.exe` as researched is a compiler that compiles mainly C.

When looking inside the visual studio code documentations and the tutorial videos, it stated to write the path to the compiler nothing more nothing less, which I have done above. I have tried to solve this error; resulted in nothing. How could I fix this error?

Error:

> [27/04/2021, 10:39:24 pm] "C:\MinGW64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'Start' will be used instead.`

Configuration File:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```